# Spring-mass oscillations, determine Period Mass relationship.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, classical-mechanics

A mass is hung from a spring; it is then pulled down and released. The mass oscillates (bounces) up and down with a certain time period . The graph below shows how the period of oscillation  depends upon the mass  for different numbers of springs attached to the mass in parallel to each other. Note: all the springs are identical, each with spring constant .

[image]

**(a) What equation shows the correct dependence of period on  and , and justify your choice using data from the graph.**

$T=2\sqrt\frac{k}{m}$             
$T=2\sqrt\frac{m}{k}$
            
$T=2\sqrt{mk}$
            
$T=2\sqrt\frac{1}{mk}$

Graph shows the Period increasing as the Mass increases, for each of the different number of springs. i.e. Period is directly proportional to the Mass.
Each of the equations:

$T=2\sqrt\frac{m}{k}$
            
$T=2\sqrt{mk}$

show a directly proportional relationship, the other 2 equations show an indirectly proportional relationship with Period decreasing as Mass increases; i believe.

**So which of these two equations correctly represent the relationship presented in the graph?**

The mass  hanging off the spring is 6.0 kg.

**(b) From the graph, determine the period of this spring-mass system. (Assume only one spring is used.)**

9.6 seconds

**(c) Calculate the number of oscillations that will pass during a 1 hour period. Give your answer to the nearest oscillation.**

1 oscillation takes 9.6 seconds

Oscillations in 1 hour = $\frac{3600}{9.6} = 375$

Does that seem correct, question seems to suggest oscillations contains decimals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent spring constant of $N$ identical springs connected in parallel is $N k$.  The graph shows a relation that is the square root function (horizontal parabola).  Therefore,

$ T = 2 \pi \sqrt{ \dfrac{m}{k} } $

is the correct choice, because, for $m = 1$, you have for one spring, $T = 4 $, and for $4$ springs $T = 2$.  This means the period $T$ is inversely proportional to the square root of $k$.

The answers to parts (b) and (c) are correct.

Comment: I think the question might be slightly flawed if you don't know k is increasing In parallel though. If you knew nothing of springs for example, and had to explain the answer purely from the equation, data on the graph and direct/indirect proportion.